# Entity Relationship not seen under Look For in Advanced Find for CRM 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have the following issue.

I have a custom entity which i have imported in 2 environments. In environment 1, the entity got imported without much difficulty and worked as I had created it. 
In the 2nd environment, the entity got imported but i can not see Created By relationship for user under Related label in Advanced find view. However, in the 1st environment and the environment that I had developed in, I can see this relationship.

I do not know why this is happening and the only way to correct it is through unsupported update to CRM Metadata Table.

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the customizations and open the attribute there is a property there that determines if a field shows in advanced find or not.  Can you check to make sure that `Searchable` is set as Yes?

[image]

Comment: yes.. That is correct. However, this only makes the attribute available for advanced find. It does not make the relation available under "Related" label in Advanced Find. I want to make the relation accessible so that i can use attributes of the related entity in my query.